# Can the clients of a RabbitMQ cluster reconnect to another Node if the one they are connected to fails?

Tags: rabbitmq

I feel like I am missing something very fundamental here.

I can bring up a RabbitMQ cluster with three nodes (rabbit1, rabbit2 and rabbit3) without an issue. Then when I start writing my microservices it seems like each client connects to only one rabbit instance. So let's say I have all my services connect to rabbit1.

If rabbit1 then goes down will my entire infrastructure blow up? Do the services have a way of switching to another rabbit node? It seems like they cannot, in which case, what is the point of having a cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone else runs into this and has trouble (like myself) finding this in the documentation, RabbitMQ does not manage client connection auto-recovery. From the [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/connections.html#automatic-recovery):

> Some client libraries provide a mechanism for automatic recovery from
>   network connection failures... Other clients may consider network
>   failure recovery to be a responsibility of the application.

So first check if you library offers auto-recovery, if not you'll have to implement it yourself.